# unable to combine dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas

i have 4 data frames. All have two columns. the first column in all the dataframes is symbol and they have the same symbols. all symbol column in each of the dataframe have 150 symbols.

now i want to combine them in one dataframe in which there will be symbol column and 4 other columns
from all the four data frames

following is the code snippet

```
result_df1 = max_open_int_ce_rows.loc[:, ['SYMBOL', '1 CE OI']]
result_df2 = second_largest_ce_rows.loc[:, ['SYMBOL','2nd CE OI']]
result_df3 = max_open_int_pe_rows.loc[:, ['SYMBOL','1 PE OI']]
result_df4 = second_largest_pe_rows.loc[:, ['SYMBOL','2nd PE OI']]

# Merge DataFrames on 'SYMBOL'
merged_df = result_df1.merge(result_df2, on='SYMBOL', how='outer') \
                .merge(result_df3, on='SYMBOL', how='outer') \
                .merge(result_df4, on='SYMBOL', how='outer') \
                .merge(result_df5, on='SYMBOL', how='outer') \
                .merge(result_df6, on='SYMBOL', how='outer') \
                .merge(result_df7, on='SYMBOL', how='outer') \
                .merge(result_df8, on='SYMBOL', how='outer')
```

i tried using merge. it gives the following error -

ValueError: 'SYMBOL' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous.

Comment: You better show the structure of any of the original dataframes, and the code for merge

Comment: Have you tried `result_df1.merge(result_df2, on = 'SYMBOL').merge(result_df3, on = 'SYMBOL').merge(result_df4, on = 'SYMBOL')`?

Comment: @Niqua I GET THE SAME ERROR - ValueError: 'SYMBOL' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous.

Comment: @AlexeyS.Larionov I have added the code for merging in the question section